# Mathematics of Poetry

Tags: reference-request, applications, ratio

Does anyone know of any sources that talk about (or know what topics I can start looking at that relate to) the mathematics behind poetry, e.g., ratios of syllables, equations for meter, frequency of different sounds made in the English language etc.?

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question - but perhaps you can derive something from [Mathematics in Poetry](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/4/vol6/Growney/MathPoetry.html) that would be of use to you?  =)

Comment: Or this [one](http://people.sju.edu/~rhall/Multi/rhythm2.pdf)?

Comment: try 'Godel, Escher, Bach', or maybe http://www.amazon.com/The-Music-Instinct-Works-Without/dp/0199896429